# React Native, how to create alarm notification (once, immediately)?

Tags: react-native, alarmmanager

My app has a "Fire Alarm" feature, when a fire incident occurs, the server will send push notification to devices.

Because it's critical alarm, I need to make it plays repeat sound, vibrate... Basically turn on everything if possible. How do I create this kind of critical alarm? even when the app was in background?

In Android, I'm reading "Schedule alarms" feature, I'm not sure if it works.

Does anyone have experience creating this kind of notification? Thank you.